# Wordpress number the posts in a category

Tags: php, wordpress

When I click on a category page on Wordpress, it lists all the posts in that category. All I want to do is number them somehow.

Here is the code in content.php

```
h2 class="entry-title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>

<div class="entry-content">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

So would I need to do a `loop` or something?

Comment: You can use `posts_per_page=x` parameter of `query_posts()` function to control the number of posts shown, refer to [query_posts() documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total post under a category page,place the given code in loop of category page.

```
 echo $item_query->found_posts;
```